# How does C++ know which attribute to use

Tags: c++

I have the incomplete class below (but the necessary is there to understand my concern). 
The following method is copying the content of a given bag (called `sac` in my code)

```
template <class T, int capInitial>
Sac<T,capInitial>& Sac<T,capInitial>::
        operator+=(Sac &b) {

    for(int i=0; i<b.getTaille(); i++){
        *this += b.sac[i];  //LINE i DON'T UNDERSTAND
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Since the class Below has 2 attributes and a `pointer` to an array. In the line mentioned above what mechanism enable to take all elements in the given `argument` and just add it to the array of the class via `*this+=b.sac[i]`, i would have done it in the following way

```
for(int i=0; i<b.getTaille(); i++){
    sac[taille++]= b.sac[i];
```

Or perhaps there is something i don't quite understand? here is the incomplete class

```
 template <class T, int capInitial>
    class IterateurSac;

    template <class T, int capInitial=64>
    class Sac {

    private:

        T* sac;
        int taille;
        int capacite;


        std::default_random_engine generator;
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution;

        void augmenterCapacite(int cap);
        void copier(const Sac &b);

    public:

        Sac() : taille(0), capacite(capInitial), generator(7437843) {
            sac= new T[capacite];
        }

template <class T, int capInitial>
Sac<T,capInitial>& Sac<T,capInitial>::
        operator+=(const T &element) {

    if (taille==capacite)
        augmenterCapacite(2*capacite);

    sac[taille++]= element;

    return *this;
}
    }
```

Comment: (These aren't "attributes")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, you can create your own behaviour for operators. Your class would need to overload `operator+=` to make this work, and that function would name the member variable to modify.

Indeed, we can see from your first code snippet that the class is *already* overloading `operator+=` to take an argument of type `Sac<T,capInitial>&`; it must have another one taking an argument of type `T` (or compatible).

What's not clear is why the class definition you later show us does not include a declaration for either of those functions.

Comment: please look at the method i just added and tell me if that's the method that enable that mechanism to work

Comment: @Bobby: Yes, it is. Although you added it in the wrong place. Next time present real code!!